# In clojurescript how can I change the namespace?

Tags: clojurescript

I am trying to change the namespace when I evaluate code with cljs.js but fully qualifying something or using (ns seems to do nothing).
Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do this in the end by doing this:

```
(cljs/eval-str (cljs/empty-state) string-to-evaulate 'foo.bar
                    {
                      :eval cljs/js-eval
                      :load load-fn
                      :source-map true}
                    (fn [result]
                      (do
                        (js/eval (:value result))
                        result))))
```

Comment: I think I'm trying to do something similar... what is your "load-fn"?

Comment: The load function is here: https://github.com/zubairq/BlocklyBuilder/blob/master/idesandboxcode/myappshare/mainapp.cljs

Comment: Sorry I did not update the question as I did get this working in the end

Comment: FWIW, I'm finding the code here very useful: https://github.com/ctford/klangmeister/tree/master/src/klangmeister/compile